# NextJS Image Error with the Src Width and Height

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I am having a problem with the image src that I am trying to upload in my dApp. I have the height and width properties set but it still shows the following error:

`Uncaught Error: Image with src "https://vivi-project.infura-ipfs.io/ipfs/Qmc5VkpgsRbiyxG1152WVfnHgZ4caqVLJDSrUPYhX9TdCP" must use "width" and "height" properties or "layout='fill'" property.`

I have the properties set as:
`

```
<Image
                            src={fileUrl}
                            alt="Picture of the NFT"
                            className="rounded mt-4"
                            width={350}
                            height={500}
                            //blurDataURL="data:..." automatically provided
                            //placeholder="blur" // Optional blur-up while loading
                          />
```

`

I have looked at solution:
[NextjS Image issue with src and default external image URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66784795/nextjs-image-issue-with-src-and-default-external-image-url)

and looked at the Nextjs documentation
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to be in my index.js file that wasn't posted in here. Make sure to check for the image src in there to have the width and height uncommented and set to appropriate sizing. Rookie mistake that was caught by icyJoseph on GitHub.
[Answer to Image Src Issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/43463)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using the `legacy`next image component instead of the next13 supported `next/image` component.

If you are using the `legacy` image component this is how you'd do it

```
import Image from "next/legacy/image";
```

You'd need the `height` and `width` property together or `layout` props to get it to work. Also, you'd need a wrapper for the image whose `position` is not `static`.

If you are using the Next 13 Image component i.e `next/image` this is how you'd import

```
import Image from "next/image";
```

This new component *needs* the `height` and `width` props unless it is a statically hosted image, in which case, you'd need to pass the `layout` props.

You can read all about it in the [next 13 image docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image) or the [next legacy image docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/legacy/image)

Comment: Hello @kanuos I am actually still under Next version 12.3.4. Would you advise that I stick to your advice on legacy image component? I did try upgrading the Next 13 yesterday but it wasn't 'playing' nice with my other dependencies which is why I downgraded back again.

Comment: I run my website using Next 12 but sooner or later I'd have to upgrade it to next 13 when it's stable enough. For the time being, using Next 12 resolves the problem. I think we have some time before we can upgrade to Next 13 which in itself should be much of a hassle.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I'll take a look at legacy next image component and the documents you linked for me.

Comment: Side note: I am also using tailwind css. It is in the global.module.css file Would this affect my image src being read for the height and properties set in another file? In the image preview, it doesn't appear to do that.

Comment: Tailwind has nothing to do with Next. Stick to the tailwind installation guide for Next and you're good to go